# Programmatically open each expansion panel in Vuetify

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am trying to programmatically open and close the expansion panels with Vuetify 2.3.5

```
<v-expansion-panels accordion>
    <v-expansion-panel v-for="(item,i) in faqs" :key="i">
        <div class="expansion-panel-header-container">
            <div class="handle"><v-icon>$drag_icon</v-icon></div>
            <v-expansion-panel-header hide-actions expand-icon="$edit">
                <span class="font-weight-bold">{{item.question}}</span>
            </v-expansion-panel-header>
            <div class="action-icons">
                <v-icon @click.native="doSomething">$edit</v-icon>
                <v-icon>$delete</v-icon>
            </div>
        </div>
    <v-expansion-panel-content>
        CONTENT GOES HERE
    </v-expansion-panel-content>
<v-expansion-panels accordion>
```

Currently the v-expansion-panel-header becomes the entire button that triggers the open and close of the panel but I would like to disable that function and trigger the open and close with this `<v-icon @click.native="doSomething">$edit</v-icon>` instead.

I can not find any documentation on how to do this.

Does anyone know how I could go about achieving this functionality?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

All you need to do is add a `v-model`. When you set the value to `null` all panels will get closed:

```html
<v-expansion-panels v-model="openedPanel" accordion>
  ...
```

```js
data () {
  return {
    openedPanel: null
  }
},
methods: {
  closeAllPanels () {
    this.openedPanel = null
  },
  openPanel (index) {
    this.openedPanel = index
  }
}
```

If you want to be able to open multiple panels at the same time, use an array instead:

```html
<v-expansion-panels v-model="openedPanel" multiple accordion>
  ...
```

```js
data () {
  return {
    openedPanel: []
  }
},
methods: {
  closeAllPanels () {
    this.openedPanel = []
  },
  openPanel (index) {
    this.openedPanel.push(index)
  },
  closePanel (index) {
    this.openedPanel.splice(index, 1)
  }
}
```

Comment: How do I open the panel?

Comment: @Jason just set `this.openedPanel` to the needed index, e.g. if you set it to 0, the first panel will get opened

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Yes, I am just trying to work out toggling the open and close. I was just about to select your answer

Comment: @Jason I updated the answer, take a look at those methods

Comment: Yes, I saw that. I only have one button I am using so I will be using the openPanel method. I now need to check and see if the panel is already open and if so close it

Comment: I am doing it like this: ```if(this.openedPanel == e) { this.openedPanel = null } else {  this.openedPanel = e }```

Comment: is there a cleaner way?

Comment: I would like to not close the other panels when a new one opens

Comment: @Jason if you don't want other panels to close, why not use the `array` method then? It allows you to add and remove the specified index without touching other ones

Comment: @Jason just add `multiple` prop to the component: `<v-expansion-panels multiple>`

Comment: @Jason glad I could help :)